# How to ignore specific words with preg_replace

Tags: php

Consider the following:

```
$string = "Hello, there! Welcome to <>?@#$!& our site<!END!>";
```

I'm trying to remove everything except for letters, numbers, spaces, and the "special tag" `<!END!>`

Using preg_replace, I can write this:

```
$string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", "", $string);
```

To remove everything except letters (both capital and lowercase), numbers, and spaces. Now if I wanted to also ignore the `<!END!>` tag, in theory I could write this:

```
$string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 <!END!>]/", "", $string);
```

However this will not specifically ignore the tag `<!END!>`, but rather any of the characters it contains. So it'll be preserving every <, >, and ! in $string.

The result:

```
"Hello there! Welcome to <>! our site<!END!>"
```

But I'm trying to get:

```
"Hello there Welcome to  our site<!END!>"
```

Based on my research, it should be possible to include a specific word to ignore in preg_replace by using the \b tags, however `"/[^A-Za-z0-9 \b<!END!>\b]/"` gave me the same result as above.

Am I doing something wrong?

Live demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/219dc36ab8aa7dfa16e8e623f5f4ba7f4b4b930d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [`(*SKIP)(*F)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) solution:

[`<!END!>(*SKIP)(FAIL)|[^A-Za-z0-9 ]`](https://regex101.com/r/02aKvP/1)

That would match:

- `<!END!>(*SKIP)(FAIL)` match `<!END!>` and then skip that match
- `|` or
- `[^A-Za-z0-9 ]` Match not using what is specified in the character class

For example:

```
$string = "Hello, there! Welcome to <>?@#$!& our site<!END!>";
$string = preg_replace("/<!END!>(*SKIP)(FAIL)|[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", "", $string);
echo $string;
```

That will result in:

> Hello there Welcome to  our site<!END!>

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/1MmU3)